# Fancy \Aboxed without redefining it

Tags: macros, tcolorbox, mathtools

I'd like to define a fancy box in `align` environments while keeping the `\Aboxed` command as it is defined by default.

What I got so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@Aboxed}{\boxed{#1#2}}{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1#2$}}{}{}%
\makeatother
\newcommand{\Asol}{\Aboxed}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Aboxed{n+1 &= 1005} \\
\Asol{n &= 1004}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to define a new command `\Asol` without changing `\Aboxed` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make copies of both `\Aboxed` and `\@Aboxed`.  Edit the copied versions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\let\Asol\Aboxed
\let\@Asol\@Aboxed
\patchcmd{\Asol}{\@Aboxed}{\@Asol}{}{}%
\patchcmd{\@Asol}{\boxed{#1#2}}{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1#2$}}{}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Aboxed{n+1 &= 1005} \\
\Asol{n &= 1004}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is this the shortest way of doing it or there is another method without using `patchcmd`?

Comment: @soundwave This is the shortest.  If you wanted to avoid `\patchcmd`, you would have to make copies of the *full* macros for `\Aboxed` and `\@Aboxed`, renaming them and editing them directly.